# Use inner join only if temporary table have values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have dynamic query where first I create a temporary table then I fill it:

```
CREATE TABLE [#SearchKeys] ([DesignKey] INT);

INSERT INTO [#SearchKeys]
    SELECT
        [pd].[DesignKey]
    FROM 
        [Project] AS [p]
    ....
```

Once it have data I just use into INNER JOIN section of my dynamic query like:

```
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DesignKey FROM #SearchKeys) AS [S] ON [S].[DesignKey] = [PD].[DesignKey]
```

Problem is I only want to add this `INNER JOIN` if temporary table have values, if not just don't execute it. How can I achieve that? Regards

Comment: I don't see any dynamic query.

Comment: What does [PD] alias, you left something out.

Answer (score 2):

I dont see dynamic query from your question. But I just give you pesudocode here

```
--Check for If Data Exist in #SearchKeys
IF Exists (SELECT 1 FROM #SearchKeys)--Condition to check value available in temp table
BEGIN
   --without INNER JOIN Query
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   -- with INNER JOIN Query
   INNER JOIN (SELECT DesignKey FROM #SearchKeys) AS [S] ON [S].[DesignKey] = [PD].[DesignKey]
END
```

Comment: This is a good, pragmatic approach, +1 from my side. But: The big *draw-back* is the fact, that this cannot be used in a `VIEW` or an *inline-table-values-function*. I try to avoid *multi-statement* approaches...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion, which is fully inlined, was this:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,Content INT);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES(10),(20),(30);

DECLARE @SearchKeys TABLE(DesignKey INT);
--Keep it empty in the first run, then decomment the insert to see the difference
--INSERT INTO @SearchKeys VALUES(20)

SELECT *
FROM @mockupTable t
LEFT JOIN @SearchKeys k ON t.Content=k.DesignKey
WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @SearchKeys)=0 OR DesignKey IS NOT NULL);
```

The `LEFT JOIN` will return all rows in any case. The `WHERE` will decide if there are filters in the SearchKey-table. In this case only rows with a corresponding key are returned.

Hint: If needed, you can easily turn your keys to an *anti-pattern* by using `IS NULL` instead of `IS NOT NULL`. In this case you'd introduce a variable and use something like `OR ((@antipattern=0 AND ...) OR (@antipattern=1 AND ...))`

The other answer by Developer_29 will be better optimized, thus faster. But in many cases we don't want *multi-statement* approaches